# Create Sencha Touch Application on Mac

Tags: xcode6, senchatouch-2.4

I am trying to create an application on **Senhcha Touch on Mac** and Use it on XCode.

I am using Sencha CMD : 6.0.1.76
           Sencha Touch Framework: 2.4.1
           Cordova On Mac : 5.2.0

When I am generating new app using terminal it is not generating app correctly.
It throws "touch" and "build" folder out of application directory.
I have created a small video for what actually is happening with me, please check this : https://mega.nz/#!a9ZzFADT!SFKa3KAfGqlloOM7L-9OrSHIeWKGTCqCiXKbJnRrG8A

Please suggest on this..

Answer (score 0):

Use Sencha CMD 5 version, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the hidden .sencha folder one directory level up from the folder you intend to be the app. try to open the folder containing your app folder in a code editor and view the contents you will probably see it.

`sencha -sdk path/to/touch-0.0.0 generate app AppName path/to/appname`